# How to customize Authorize.net Hosted Form Pop Up For iPhone and Android?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, asp.net

I am unable to customize Authorize.net Hosted Form Pop Up for iPhone and Android.

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone, The following delegate function will be called when the connection requires authentication challenge. You can display an alert within this function if you want.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Suresh, but i am using ASP.net only not native iPhone App.

Comment: I don't think you can do it on web side(I mean in ASP.net).

Comment: i implemented already in website but one module i developed for mobile device that is creating problem, it is showing Authorize Pop Up Form.

Comment: I thought you are developing an iPhone application also. By default iPhone will show that authorize pop up. And even Safari will do the same. If you really need to get rid of that alert, you have to get a certificate from apple and import that into your web service (I don't have much knowledge in this). I don't know if you can customize that alert.

Comment: Yes i am developing module for iPhone but it is in asp.net only. The Hosted Form Pop Up is generated dynamically by test.authorize.net , i need to design this pop up as per my requirement.